# How to disable Interceptors for 1 request in React?

Tags: reactjs, axios, interceptor

I have Interceptors.js file under src file. I am importing it in the files which I need. But it is also working for 1 request which I do not want to use the Interceptors even I do not import it. How can I disable Interceptors for this request?

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't have some important information, but I'll take a guess and say you mean you don't want your Axios Interceptors to be run for some request.

If that's the case, you can test, in the beginning of the interceptor code, if the request being called is **not** the one you want to skip the interceptor for. Something like this:

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
  if (!config.url?.includes('/your-endpoint-here')) { // <----- Here you test for the endpoint you want to skip
    // Here you do whatever should be done for all the other requests.
  }
  return config;
});
```

I've done exactly that to add some headers to all my API requests, with the exception of one.

Comment: Of course! Your solution works for some cases but my case was different. I did add a flag where I call the api and make it false and then check it in the interceptors! Thanks for your reply.